# Auto trimming trailing space db2 fixed length columns - JDBC SQL

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, jvm, db2

Its been a year I started to work on DB2 I can't tell how much I like other database(Oracle etc). Basically I'm stuck with the fixed length columns in legacy tables with trailling space in DB2.

I'm currently working on an existing Java reporting module which basically pulls over 150+ columns and most of them are fixed length columns. I've plain old JDBC queries like this all over the application. I know if I use TRIM() or LTRIM() on each column will take off the unnecessary spaces. But I'm looking for an efficient and easy solution instead of going across the application changing the SQL queries.

Lately, this has been become a huge heap issue (OutOfMemoryError) on the JVM when the report gets too big.

Comment: Is it possible to calculate the data for the report from the rows without having to store the whole strings, like averages, or do you need to store all the row's data at once in order to compute the values?

Comment: What is the data structure of your report?  Are you concatenating strings  continously

Comment: Its a simple report which is being exported to excel from jdbc resultset.

Comment: @jrtapsell. No calculation performed. Its simply retrived and exported. Thats it.

Comment: Can you show pseudocode for how you are processing the rows, if you are streaming them correctly then the amount should only affect the runtime, the memory use shouldn't be too bad

Comment: That's another thing, its not streamed continuously. All the data is load to a domain object which get added to a list and later at the end written to a file. I know this is pathetic but for processing 100k rows of 150+ columns shouldn't take more than a gb heap. right?

Comment: There is no magic bullet, you will need to trim the column values either in your SQL, or in Java when building your domain objects.